# Reading external files more efficiently in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, batch-file, external, textscan

I have the following problem, i have develop a code to search into large files containing data, the process become too slow and even in some computers it consumes all the available computer resources.

```
nodo=str2num(get(handles.nodo,'string'));                                 
PATHNAME = uigetdir('', 'Selecciona el directorio donde están los bfins');
files = dir(fullfile(PATHNAME,'*.bfin') );                                
curr_folder=pwd;                                                          
cd(PATHNAME);                                                             
archivo={files.name}';                                                    
for i=1:numel(archivo)                                                    
        [fid{i}, errmsg]=fopen(files(i).name)                                 
        disp(errmsg);                                                         
        Datos{i}=textscan(fid{i}, '%s  %f %s %f %s %f ','Headerlines',2);     
        AllNodos{i}=Datos{1,i}{1,2};                                          
        AllTemp{i}=Datos{1,i}{1,4};                                           
end                                                                       
cd(curr_folder)                                                           
for i=1:size(AllNodos,2)                                                  
        sets{i}=cat(2, AllNodos{1,i}, AllTemp{1,i});                          
end                                                                       
for i=1:size(AllNodos,2)                                                  
        vectn{i}=AllNodos{1,i};                                               
        r{i}=find(vectn{i}==nodo);                                            
        Temps{i}=AllTemp{1,i}(r{i});                                          
end  
    %Write Excel File
[FileName, PathName] = uiputfile('*.xlsx', 'Escribe un archivo excel con las    temperaturas...')
savingas=fullfile(PathName,FileName);
a=archivo';
B=cat(1,a,Temps); 
xlswrite(savingas,[B])
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(savingas); %# open file (enter full path!)
ewb.Worksheets.Item(1).Name = num2str(nodo); %# rename 1st sheet
ewb.Save %# save to the same file
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

What the code really does is to find in to the files the location of a string and then find another variable(just a cntrl+f operation) and reproduce them in an excel sheet any help regarding this would be appreciated.

EDIT----
Thank you very much for all your comments, i came up with the following code that saves a lot of unnecesary time that it used to take by storing variables:

```
    for i=1:num_archivo
   [fid(i), errmsg]=fopen(files(i).name)
   disp(errmsg);
   Datos=textscan(fid(i), '%s  %f %s %f','delimiter',',','HeaderLines',hl);
   AllNodos=Datos(1,2);
   AllTemp=Datos(1,4);
   for k=1:numel(nodo)
    r{i,k}=find(AllNodos{1,1}==nodo(k));
    Temps{i,k}=AllTemp{1,1}(r{i,k});
   end
   end
```

Comment: What size are the files, roughly and about how many files are we talking?

Comment: Files are about 25Mb each file, and about 8 files to process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textscan` itself is very fast so it may be eating CPU, but you're not likely to improve on it performance-wise. However, it looks like you're not performing any sort of pre-allocation for your cell arrays. This means that Matlab may be constantly reallocating memory. Use [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) to create an empty cell array of the desired size:

```
num_archivo = numel(archivo);
Datos = cell(1,num_archivo);
AllNodos = cell(1,num_archivo);
AllTemp = cell(1,num_archivo);
for i = 1:num_archivo
    ...
end
...
```

(Though `Datos` should probably not be a cell at @Lazarus pointed out.) You should do the same sort of thing for the other loops with `sets`, `vectn`, etc.

One other thing that I'd be sure to do is call [`fclose(fid);`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) immediately after you're done reading `files(i).name` so that you don't have a bunch of open file pointers. Also, there seems to be no reason for saving the file id `fid` to a cell array as you don't use it outside of the loop. Even if you did, a regular vector (allocated with `numel(archive)` elements) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would depend on how large your datasets are.  But the first change I would make is to set `Datos{i}` to just `Datos` since you are only using it in the for loop.  This way matlab doesn't have to allocate more space.

The second change I'd make is to include the the `cat` and `find` function within the first for loop, so that you can also replace `Allnodos{i}` with `Allnodos` and also save on the allocation issue.

This should help with the resource issue; it may not help with the speed issue if textscan is the limiting factor.  Using `tic` and `toc` before and after textscan will let you know how long it is taking.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your solution?, i tried what you said, but i get the error "index exceed matrix dimensions", hanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what size your "large" files actually have and how many there are.
Check your code using the profiler:

```
profile on;
<run your code>
profile viewer
```

I'd suspect that `fopen` and the `textscan` lines are the evil ones...

Generally in anything concerning reading files, the bottleneck is mostly disk i/o - not CPU.
In that case you can't really do a lot except for doing things in parallel maybe, which unfortunately is not that easy in matlab - if you're not willing to pay.

Comment: could you elaborate on the parallel operation, i suspect that you are talking about the in-parallel computer toolbox; i really don't care if the process take much time but while i running this code i can't use my computer for other tasks, is the anything to do about it?

Comment: Yep - you could use parallel code to make things faster. But if this single process is already slowing down your/any computer (or only the one matlab-instance?), then more processes would probably make things even worse...